# Wordpress and wp_insert_post not working

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm doing an webapp that works with a wordpress website.

Until yesterday all works like a charm, but from today, when i save the post on wordpress db, it now not working...
Not give me error (php error or wordpress error), but simply a white page.

This is my full code:(sorry for many commented lines and echo, but i'm testing)

The important part:

```
  // Create post object
  $my_post = array(
    'post_title'    => $article_title,
    'post_name'   => $article_title,
    'post_content'  => $article_content,
    'post_status'   => 'pending',
    'post_author'   => 1
  );

  // Insert the post into the database
  wp_insert_post($my_post, TRUE);// try first time

  $post_status = "pending";
  $post_type = "post";
  $post_parent = "0";

  $post_ID = (int) $wpdb->insert_id;
  echo $post_ID; die;
```

Yesterday with a simple wp_insert_post(my_post); all worked fine, today (of course i think i edited some files...or i don't now), not works more and not give me error.

What do you think ?

Thank you, really!

**EDIT: The problem was that i not insert post_category and wp need it!**

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the $post_id with the wp_insert_post() function...

```
$post_ID = wp_insert_post($my_post, TRUE);// try first time
```

Then you can dump out the $post_ID variable to get the ID or the error.

```
var_dump($post_ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_func' );

function my_func()  {
$my_post = '';
if( get_page_by_title($article_title,'OBJECT','post') == NULL )
$my_post= array(
    'post_title'    => $article_title,
    'post_name'   => $article_title,
    'post_type'  => 'post',
    'post_content'  => $article_content,
    'post_status'   => 'pending',
    'post_author'   => 1
);
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
echo 'Post ID - '.$post_id;
}
```