# wordpress 4.0 wp_insert_post() crash to white screen

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to submit a new post under a custom post-type. When I run the submit code the post is created in the database, but the php script itself seems to be crashing and just presenting a white screen. I'm not seeing any php or wp_errors being raised either and trying something as simple as wrapping it in a try catch doesn't allow me to pick up what's happening.

I saw a similar issue in;

[Wordpress and wp_insert_post not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960428/wordpress-and-wp-insert-post-not-working?rq=1)

But their solution unfortunately didn't work for me, I'm probably missing something obvious but i've stripped it back to a simple post and am still getting the problem.

I'm sure I'm missing something, but I just can't spot what it is.

Here's the code I'm using;

```
    $post = array(
        'post_content' => 'Content',
        'post_title' => 'Title',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'our-briefings',
        'comment_status' => 'closed',
        'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'post_date_gmt' => gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'post_author' => 0
    );

    $response = wp_insert_post($post);
    echo 'Complete';
```

`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: are you sure you have error reporting enabled properly? http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: Aaaand there's the stupid thing I was missing.

Thanks nunorbatista, I can fix it when I can see the errors!

Comment: Anytime. When developing in Wordpress always, always but always have Debug Enabled.